# Retrieving the path to all data.frame class objects in rData files

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion

I have multiple .rData files whose top level Global Environment variables are a mix of data.frames, lists, deeply nested lists. I know that many of the nested lists have within them data.frame types, but I'm having trouble retrieving the path to them.

I had a faced a similar problem before with another type of class using the following code

```
names(rapply(mget(ls(.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv), length, classes="fluor.spectral.data", how="unlist"))
```

and while not the most elegant solution, it achieved what I needed and quickly. returning names like "Fluor.Spec.WA.M12.SC.13" which then allows me to manipulate the object after formating the '.' into '$'.

Can someone help me retrieve the path to all data.frame class types, nested or otherwise in highly variable .rData files? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all data.frames loaded in the global environment, either present as individual object or as element of a nested list, use `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extension of base `rrapply`).

```r
library(rrapply)

w <- data.frame(1)
x <- list(1, 2, 3)
y <- 5
z <- list(1, 2, list(1, df = data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)))

rrapply(as.list(.GlobalEnv), classes = "data.frame", how = "flatten")
#> $w
#>   X1
#> 1  1
#> 
#> $df
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
```

Setting `classes = "data.frame"` avoids recursion into data.frame columns (as base `rapply` would do), and `how = "flatten"` will return the collected data.frames as a flattened list.

NB: If you want to return the complete object paths to the found data.frames, set `how = "prune"` instead of `how ="flatten"`:

```r
rrapply(as.list(.GlobalEnv), classes = "data.frame", how = "prune")
#> $w
#>   X1
#> 1  1
#> 
#> $z
#> $z[[1]]
#> $z[[1]]$df
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
```

---

**Edit:** In order to also return data.frames present in slots of some S4-class, a possible way to extend the above call would be:

```r
## define S4-class with a data.frame in "df" slot
userClass <- setClass("user", slots = c(df = "data.frame"))
v <- userClass(df = data.frame(user = 1))

rrapply(as.list(.GlobalEnv), 
                   classes = c("data.frame", "user"), 
                   f = function(x) {
                     if(class(x) == "user") {
                       slot(x, "df")
                     } else {
                       x
                     }
                   },
                   how = "flatten")
#> $v
#>   user
#> 1    1
#> 
#> $w
#>   X1
#> 1  1
#> 
#> $df
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
```

In this case, `classes = c("data.frame", "user")` will check for data.frames and S4-objects of class `"user"`. The `f` function applied to the object, returns the object itself if it is a data.frame or the `"df"` slot if it is an S4-object.

Note that this code assumes that the S4-class name is known as well as the slot(s) which contain the data.frame objects.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Although, the function does not do what I need it to do, I think now I understand the reason why. The nested data I'm working with contain a special class we have defined at various depths. I think R refers to these as S4 objects. The data.frames themselves live in these objects and are accessed like so: "ownDefinedClass"@<data.frame variable> I think rrapply is not 'allowed' to penetrate them and retrieve what I need (at least I think that's whats going on").  Your code does retrieve the data.frames outside of these objects, Thanks!

Comment: See the edited response to extract data.frames from a given slot of an S4-class as well. For context, `rrapply` recurses into nested lists (same as base `rapply`), if the S4-object is not of class `"list"`, `rrapply` will not recurse into it.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot :)